# Improving performance of a Rails controller method that returns a serialized hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

Would anyone be willing to give me advice on how I can improve the performance of the following controller method?

```
def index
    @contacts = Hash[current_user.company.contacts.map {|contact| [contact.id, ContactSerializer.new(contact).as_json[:contact]] }]

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { contacts: @contacts } }
    end
end
```

This returns the following data structure:

```
{
    contacts: {
        79: {
            id: 79,
            first_name: "Foo",
            last_name: "Bar",
            email: "t@t.co",
            engagement: "0%",
            company_id: 94,
            created_at: " 9:41AM Jan 30, 2016",
            updated_at: "10:57AM Feb 23, 2016",
            published_response_count: 0,
            groups: {
                test: true,
                test23: false,
                Test222: false,
                Last: false
            },
            invites: [
                {
                    id: 112,
                    email: "t@t.co",
                    status: "Requested",
                    created_at: "Jan 30, 2016, 8:48 PM",
                    date_submitted: null,
                    response: null
                }
            ],
            responses: [ ],
            promotions: [
                {
                    id: 26,
                    company_id: 94,
                    key: "e5cb3bc80b58c29df8a61231d0",
                    updated_at: "Feb 11, 2016, 2:45 PM",
                    read: null,
                    social_media_posts: [ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        81: {
            id: 81,
            first_name: "Foo2",
            last_name: "Bar2",
            email: "foobar2@foobar.com",
            engagement: "0%",
            company_id: 94,
            created_at: "12:55PM Feb 04, 2016",
            updated_at: " 4:25PM Feb 19, 2016",
            published_response_count: 0,
            groups: {
                test: true,
                test23: true,
                Test222: false,
                Last: false
            },
            invites: [
                {
                    id: 116,
                    email: "foobar2@foobar.com",
                    status: "Requested",
                    created_at: "Feb 22, 2016, 9:10 PM",
                    date_submitted: null,
                    response: null
                }
            ],
            responses: [ ],
            promotions: [
                {
                    id: 26,
                    company_id: 94,
                    key: "e5cb3bc80b58c29df8a61231d0",
                    updated_at: "Feb 11, 2016, 2:45 PM",
                    read: null,
                    social_media_posts: [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need the `index` method to return a hash where the the keys are the contact IDs, as opposed to an Array, which is what would normally be returned. Additionally, I pass each contact through the serializer so that I get all associated data that my client needs.

This method works fine when there are only a few contacts, however when I have 100 or 1000, it really slows down. I benchmarked it with 100 contacts and it took 4 seconds to finish, which is abysmal. I'm wondering how I can improve my code to get the *exact same* output in a more performant manner. The key here is that the output needs to remain unchanged. I have no interest in modifying the client-side code (it depends on this data structure for numerous applications), so all changes need to occur on the server-side.

Here is my `ContactSerializer` for reference:

```
class ContactSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :engagement, :company_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :published_response_count, :groups
    has_many :invites
    has_many :responses
    has_many :promotions

    def groups
        Hash[object.company.groups.map {|group| [group.name, object.groups.include?(group)] }]
    end

    def published_response_count
        object.responses.where(published: true).count
    end

    def created_at
        object.created_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M%p %b %d, %Y")
    end

    def updated_at
        object.updated_at.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%l:%M%p %b %d, %Y")
    end

    def engagement
        object.engagement
    end
end
```

For what it's worth, I am fully aware that returning JSON data like this from Rails is not a great practice and have since moved away from it completely. Unfortunately this piece of code was written quite awhile ago and I can't afford the time to do a full rewrite of the client side to consume a standard output such as an array of contacts.

Comment: "Refactoring" is changing the structure of code for the sake of the structure. Improving performance isn't refactoring. I edited accordingly. As for performance, the slowness is probably due to repeated queries when looking up groups, invites and/or promotions, and can probably be fixed by adding `includes` to the contacts query. Look in log/development.log and see what queries are repeated and/or slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started looking into the queries that we're being generated by ActiveRecord.

I realized after a while though that the queries were only accounting for a few ms of the total processing time. I started benchmarking the code starting with the base query `company.contacts` and then gradually adding on methods I had, such as `map` and then passing each contact into the serializer, and finally calling `as_json[:contact]` on the object returned by `ContactSerializer.new(contact)`.

What I found is that calling `as_json[:contact]` on the serialized object was consuming an average of about 30ms (averaged over 100 runs) per contact. The reason I had that was to remove the root `contact` node from the JSON that was returned.

When I benchmarked my original code with 198 contacts, it took an average of 10400ms over 10 runs. When I removed `as_json[:contact]` and set `root false` on `ContactSerializer`, as described by "[Abusing ActiveModel::Serializers for HAL](http://blog.oestrich.org/2012/10/abusing-active-model-serializers-for-hal/)", I was able to cut the time down from 10400ms to 87ms, while returning the exact same structure to the client, which is astounding.

It might be possible to shave a few ms off that with some query optimizations, but anything else at this point is just icing on the cake.